# Django-widget-tweaks : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'widget_tweaks'

Tags: django, github, workflow, django-widget-tweaks

I am new to Django and also github CI/CD pipelines. I am working on a django project and I installed  widget_tweaks via pip install django-widget-tweaks on the command prompt. The program and forms are working fine on the browser with no errors. However, I have a ci/cd pipeline on github to automate testing and when I try push the code, I get the following error:

```
Run pip3 install --user django
Collecting django
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/75/42/f59a8ebf14be6d17438f13042c775f53d3dfa71fff973e4aef64ca89582c/Django-3.1.6-py3-none-any.whl (7.8MB)
Collecting pytz (from django)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/70/94/784178ca5dd892a98f113cdd923372024dc04b8d40abe77ca76b5fb90ca6/pytz-2021.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510kB)
Collecting sqlparse>=0.2.2 (from django)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/14/05/6e8eb62ca685b10e34051a80d7ea94b7137369d8c0be5c3b9d9b6e3f5dae/sqlparse-0.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (42kB)
Collecting asgiref<4,>=3.2.10 (from django)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/89/49/5531992efc62f9c6d08a7199dc31176c8c60f7b2548c6ef245f96f29d0d9/asgiref-3.3.1-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pytz, sqlparse, asgiref, django
Successfully installed asgiref-3.3.1 django-3.1.6 pytz-2021.1 sqlparse-0.4.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/runner/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/runner/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/runner/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/runner/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/runner/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'widget_tweaks'
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

My ci.yml file for the ci/cd pipeline looks like this:

```
name: Testing
on: push

jobs:
  test_project:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Run Django unit tests
      run: |

        pip3 install --user django
        python3 manage.py test
```

Comment: your code requires django-widget-tweaks  -> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'widget_tweaks'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: I added "pip3 install django-widget-tweaks" to the ci.yml file for the github CICD pipeline